# How to use move to selected items in listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a listview. Which is refreshed when reached at the end of the list. But when list is refreshed the selection reset and first item shows selected. So have used setSelection(selectedItem), it makes that row selected but moved it top of the screen. I want it should remain at the bottom. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `smoothScrollToPosition (int position);`

This will make the listview scroll to the position of the item. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) for more info;